# Can I use FULL OUTER JOIN in access VBA?

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I know I can't user FULL OUTER JOINs in access query objects, and instead need to UNION a left and a right join. Can I avoid this extra business when creating recordsets within VBA, or does VBA use the same SQL system?

For example:

```
Recordset = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(_
"SELECT Table1.Field1, Table2.Field2 FROM Table1" & _
"FULL OUTER JOIN Table2 On Table1.Field1 = Table2.Field1")
```

Or do I have to do something like this:

```
Recordset = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(_
"SELECT Table1.Field1, Table2.Field2 FROM Table1" & _
"LEFT JOIN Table2 On Table1.Field1 = Table2.Field1" & _
"UNION SELECT Table1.Field1, Table2.Field2 FROM Table1" & _
"RIGHT JOIN Table2 On Table1.Field1 = Table2.Field1")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends which database you are trying to connect to. If you are connecting to a database which supports `FULL OUTER JOIN`, then you could use `FULL OUTER JOIN` from VBA.

Since you're using `CurrentDb.OpenRecordset`, you are querying with the Access / Jet database engine, and `FULL OUTER JOIN` is not supported.

If you are targeting another RDBMS which does support `FULL OUTER JOIN`, then you could create a pass-through query with `FULL OUTER JOIN` and call `OpenRecordset` on that query.

Comment: That'll do it. Would that be a mite slower than a join though?

Comment: @IsaacReefman Yes and no. I assume the Access database engine could still make use of appropriate indexes even with this query. Also, if you don't have that many records, it may not make a difference.

Comment: @IsaacReefman I've just realized that the two queries are not the same. The `UNION` method would include even cases where `Table1.JoinField` is not `NULL`, but simply doesn't match anything in `Table2.JoinField`.

Comment: I'll have to keep learning about how the indexing works. I'm pretty sure the number of records I'll be dealing with are tiny, as far as speed is concerned, but as I've just started learning this stuff now, I want to try to learn best practices from the start rather than just having to re-learn further down the track.

Comment: @IsaacReefman I've dropped the whole "cross join" alternative; it generally returns different results than `FULL OUTER JOIN`.

Comment: I was under the impression that a combine of a left + right join results in the same thing as a outer join. You can always add a condition for not null on the join table, but then that not going to get you the right answer.  The right join most certainly will result in table1 nulls. I mean, you can use two left joins, but just put table2 first in the second join. With a left, right, or outer join, the other table rows don't have to exist - you certainly get nulls in this case when the other table does not have a matching record - that is the whole idea here.